# Storing like count for a post in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it a good idea to store like count in the following format?

like table:

```
u_id | post_id | user_id
```

And `count(u_id)` of a post?

What if there were thousands of likes for each post? The like table is going to be filled with billions of rows after a few months.

What are other efficient ways to do so?

Comment: indexing, partitioning

Comment: @hjpotter92, so does it mean it's still okay to store the likes count like that if I do indexing and partitioning?

Comment: sounds like that would be a good problem to have, and therefore money to support it. More likely you will have thousands of likes after a few months

Comment: A major design consideration that you did not mention  - what are the consistency requirements?  Would you expect that you are going to query the the underlying data source (your proposed table) every time you need to display the like count (a strong consistency situation), or do you expect that you will have the like count cached somehow at the post level, with the count value perhaps not always being updated to the millisecond. This decision will impact your design.  Also the use cases around how you display this information will impact your design. You are not giving much info here.

Comment: Based on my above comment, I feel this question is defined too broadly.

Answer (score 14):

In two words answer is : yes , it is OK. (to store data about each *like* any user did for any post).

But I want just to separate or transform it to several questions:

Q. Is there other way to `count(u_id)`? or even better:

```
SELECT COUNT(u_id) FROM likes WHERE post_id = ?
```

A. Why not? you can save count in your `post` table and increase/decrease it every time when user like/dislike the post. You can set trigger (stored procedure) to automate this action. And then to get counter you need just:

```
SELECT counter FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?
```

If you like previous Q/A and think that it is good idea I have next question:

Q. Why do we need `likes` table then?

A. That depends of your application design and requirements. According to the columns set you posted : `u_id, post_id, user_id` (I would even add another column `timestamp`). Your requirements is to store info about **user** as well as about **post** when it liked. That means you can recognize if user already liked this post and refuse multilikes. If you don't care about multilikes or historical timeline and stats you can delete your `likes` table.

Last question I see here:

Q. *The like table is going to be filled with billions of rows after a few months.*  isn't it?

A. I wish you that success but IMHO you are 99% wrong. to get just 1M records you need 1000 active users (which is very very good number for personal startup (you are building whole app with no architect or designer involved?))  and **EVERY** of those users should like **EVERY** of 1000 posts if you have any.
My point here is: fortunately you have enough time till your database become really big and that would hurt your application. Till your table get 10-20M of records you can do not worry about size and performance.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: Thank you. It is not very best, but just some my thoughts.

Comment: @Alex storing the count as the field "counter" in a table is storing non-relational data in relational database and the cause of future pain. You've denormalized the table now.